# Why is there an error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when using an ImageSlider in a recyclerView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidimageslider

I am trying to show images in an `ImageSlider` in a recyclerView. What I have done is, as the images to be fetched from `Firebase` storage, I created an array of SlideModel within the adapter class. There will be a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 5 images. Following is how I have done this.

My code seems to work as I can see data in the remoteImages (SlideModel ArrayList) in the `Logcat`. But, when I add the last line of code, which is `holder.itemView.image_slider.setImageList(remoteImages, ScaleTypes.FIT)`, my app crashes with the  following error. Without it, the app works fine but there are no images in the slider.

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.get(Platform.java:85)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1015)
    at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader.<init>(OkHttp3Downloader.java:71)
    at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader.<init>(OkHttp3Downloader.java:50)
    at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader.<init>(OkHttp3Downloader.java:40)
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:848)
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.get(Picasso.java:683)
    at com.denzcoskun.imageslider.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:71)
    at com.denzcoskun.imageslider.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:25)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27131)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27131)
```

I have `implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.0'` in my `build.gradle`

Following is the `XML` code for the `ImageSlider` which is a part of my itemlayout for the recyclerView.

```
    <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
    android:id="@+id/image_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
    app:iss_period="2500"
    app:iss_delay="0"/>
```

Following is part of my `ItemListAdapter.kt`.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position]

        val numOfImages = model.image_count
        val remoteImages: ArrayList<SlideModel> = ArrayList()


        if (holder is MyViewHolder) {

            when (numOfImages) {
                1 -> {
                    
                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.toString())
                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.size.toString())
                }
                2 -> {
                   
                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image2,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.toString())
                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.size.toString())
                }
                3 -> {
                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image2,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image3,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.toString())
                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.size.toString())
                }
                4 -> {
                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image2,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image3,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image4,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.toString())
                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.size.toString())
                }
                5 -> {
                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image2,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image3,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image4,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    remoteImages.add(
                        SlideModel(
                            model.image5,
                            model.title,
                            ScaleTypes.FIT
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.toString())
                    Log.d("TAG", remoteImages.size.toString())
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d("TAG", "There are no images")
                }
            }

holder.itemView.image_slider.setImageList(remoteImages, ScaleTypes.FIT)

    }
```

Comment: Any help on this would highly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can pull all the logcat error and add your full adapter code?